# mysql query to count id

Tags: mysql

Using mysql I am trying to count the ID from all tables `where tid='any tid'`
I have tried following query, its giving `"Column 'tid' in where clause is ambiguous"`.
Do I need to use join ?

```
SELECT count('id') as reccount
   FROM table1,table2,table3
   WHERE tid= '101'
   AND `status` =  1
```

I have table structure like,

```
table 1:
------------------------------
id      tid    status ........ 
1       101       1
2       102       1

table 2:
------------------------------
id      tid    status ........ 
 1      101      1
 2      102      1

table 3:
------------------------------
id      tid     status....... 
 1      101       1
 2      102       1

table 4: It contains tid 
--------------------------
tid     tname .....
101      xyz
102      abc
```

Comment: Probably you wanted to use UNION.

Comment: you are using cartisian product which will not fetch desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide desired output, but if your intent is to get just a total number of rows (deducing from your original query) from all three tables then you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS reccount
  FROM 
    (SELECT `id` FROM table1 
     WHERE tid= '101' AND `status` =  1
     UNION ALL
    SELECT `id` FROM table2 
     WHERE tid= '101' AND `status` =  1
     UNION ALL
    SELECT `id` FROM table3
     WHERE tid= '101' AND `status` =  1) t
```

Here is **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5eec/4)**

Answer (score 0):

Since you're collecting rows from each of the tables, not joining them, you need to do UNIONs, as in:

```
 SELECT count('id') as reccount
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.tid= '101'
    AND `status` =  1
UNION
 SELECT count('id') as reccount
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.tid= '101'
    AND `status` =  1
UNION
 SELECT count('id') as reccount
    FROM table3
    WHERE table3.tid= '101'
    AND `status` =  1
```

Explanation: Doing `from table1, table2, table3` will do a join between all of those tables. Since there is no join criteria, it does every possible join, e.g. every possible combination of one row from table1, one row from table2 and one row from table3 will have a result in that kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNIONS

```
SELECT count('id') as reccount , 'Table1' AS table   FROM table1    WHERE tid= '101'    AND `status` =  1
UNION
SELECT count('id') as reccount , 'Table2' AS table    FROM table2   WHERE tid= '101'    AND `status` =  1
UNION
SELECT count('id') as reccount , 'Table3' AS table    FROM table3   WHERE tid= '101'    AND `status` =  1
```

This will give you the count like this

```
reccount | table
   5         table1  
   10        table2
   15        table3
```

5,10 and 15 are count for example if you want answer in only 1 row you can use @peterm's answer

Answer (score 0):

See below SQL :

```
SELECT reccount_1 + reccount_2 +  reccount_3 as total_count FROM
(
    SELECT count(`id`) as reccount_1
    FROM table1
    WHERE tid= '101'
    AND `status` =  1
    UNION
    SELECT count(`id`) as reccount_2
    FROM table2
    WHERE tid= '101'
    AND `status` =  1
    UNION 
    SELECT count(`id`) as reccount_3
    FROM table3
    WHERE tid= '101'
    AND `status` =  1
) 
as temp_table
```